# Second order low-pass filter algorithm

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

I need to filter some noise from a signal and a simple RC first order filter seems not to be enough. I've been looking around but I haven't found algorithms for other filters (although many examples of how to do it with analogue circuits). Can somebody pinpoint where can I find such algorithms? Or at least write one here?

For clarification: I take the signal from an oscilloscope, and I only have one cycle. This cycle looks a little bit like:

```
125 * (x > 3 ? exp(-(x - 3) / 2) : exp(5*(x - 3)))
```

Now, the signal not always have that shape and I need to compute the derivate of the signal, which is easy if not because when one zooms the signal enough (each point is 160 nano seconds appart) you can see a lot of noise. So, before computing derivatives I need to flattern the signal.

Comment: If it's TRUE white noise (static) it's at all frequencies equally and unfilteranle. What kind of noise is it really?

Comment: I think what he is asking for is to be able to filter out white noise over some frequency band. Say for example, the signal is in the band 1Mhz to 10Mhz, then having a low pass filter with cutoff more than 10Mhz is appropriate.

Comment: How about just choosing a filter from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(signal_processing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for how to design a higher order filter than a simple first order, how about choosing a filter from here:[wiki on Filter_(signal_processing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28signal_processing%29)

Just hypothesizing about your question, so here are a couple of design points.

1) You probably don't want to have ripple (varying gain) in your pass band, as that would distort your signal.

2) You probably don't care about having ripple in your stop band, as the signal should be close to 0 there anyway.

3) The higher the order of the filter, the more it looks like a ideal square shaped filter.

4) The higher the rolloff the better, you want to cut down on the noise outside of your passband as quickly as possible.

5) You may or may not care about "group delay", which is a measure of the distortion caused by different frequencies taking different times to pass through the filter. For audio, you probably want a not too high group delay, as you can imagine having different frequency components undergoing different time (and thus phase) shifts will cause some distortion.

Once you select the filter you want based on these (and possibly other) considerations, then simply implement it using some topology, like those mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_filter_topology)

Answer (score 0):

With only a vague description of your requirements it's hard to give any specific suggestions.

You need to specify the parameters of your filter: sample rate, cut-off frequency, width of transition band, pass-band ripple, minimum stop-band rejection, whether phase and group delay are an issue, etc. Once you have at least some of these parameters pinned down then you can start the process of selecting an appropriate filter design, i.e. basic filter type, number of stages, etc.

It would also be helpful to know what kind of signal you want to filter - is it audio, or something else ? How many bits per sample ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a good definition of your signal, a good analysis of your noise, and a clear understanding of the difference between the two, in order to determine what algorithms might be appropriate for removing one and not eliminating information in the other.  Then you need to define the computational environment (integer or float ALU, add and multiply cycles?), and set a computational budget.  There's a big difference between a second-order IIR and a giga-point FFT.

Some very commonly used 2nd-order digital filters are described in [RBJ's biquad cookbook](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt).